# Technical reasons behind Go's strange syntax

Tags: go

I recently started learning to Go, and I am quite confused as to why it has a strange "non-traditional" syntax unlike other languages (C, C++, C#, JAVA)

For example, a code like this in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(a int, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func main() {
    numbers := [4] int {1, 2, 3, 4}

    for _,n := range numbers {
        result := sum(n, 2)
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

But, could be written something like in some languages:

```
package main

import "io"

int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b
}

void main() {
    int numbers[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    
    foreach (n in range(numbers)) {
        result = sum(n, 2)
        io.print(result)
    }
}
```

So my question is, is there any technical reason behind this syntax, or is it just a personal preference of the team? Especially that the team behind Go used "C Language" to write Go, which means it would've made much more sense to type it in C-Style syntax ?

Comment: You can find answer to your questions in [Golang FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq).

Comment: Actually it’s C that has strange syntax, it’s just you’re used to it. Go has had a lot of thought put into this, read Rob Pike’s explanation : https://blog.golang.org/declaration-syntax

Comment: You got it completely wrong. Go's syntax is the normal one of Pascal and Oberon. Do you think C's spiral rule is nice, clever and easy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import "io"
```

Go has `fmt` and `io` packages, although they do have some overlap. For example, `fmt.Fprint` lets you write to any `io.Writer`, and `fmt.Fscan` lets you read from any `io.Reader`.

Similarly you can write to console with `io.Copy(os.Stdout, something)`, and read from console with `io.Copy(something, os.Stdin)`.

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
```

I think I read that by having `func` first, it makes lexical parsing much faster. Also Go function can have named return values:

```
func sum(a int, b int) (n int)
```

I am not sure how you'd do that with the other syntax.

```
int numbers[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Go syntax allows you to omit the type, which you can't do with C.

```
foreach (n in range(numbers))
```

Go doesn't have a `while` keyword, for the reason that less keywords again makes for faster lexical parsing. Instead you have different `for` invocations:

```
var n int
for {
   if n > 9 {
      break
   }
   println(n)
   n++
}

var n int
for n < 9 {
   println(n)
   n++
}

for n := 0; n < 9; n++ {
   println(n)
}

for range numbers {
   println("hello")
}

for index := range numbers {
   println(index)
}

for index, value := range numbers {
   println(index, value)
}
```

For this:

```
result = sum(n, 2)
```

Go has two different syntax for variable assignment:

```
result := 1
result = 2
```

First is a declaration, second is assigning to an already declared variable.

```
io.print(result)
```

`fmt.Println` is uppercase, because any function that starts with an uppercase letter is a "public" function. This saves on typing `public` or `pub` everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Few points that I'd like to highlight:

1. Go is inspired by many languages and not just C.

- **C**: statement and expression syntax
- **Pascal**: declaration syntax
- **Modula 2, Oberon 2**: packages
- **CSP, Occam, Newsqueak, Limbo, Alef**: concurrency
- **BCPL**: the semicolon rule
- **Smalltalk**: methods
- **Newsqueak**: <-, :=
- **APL**: iota
- There are more

2. From when `foreach` and `range` become C-style syntax?
3. Third, don't confuse "For" statements with `for` clause and `range` clause. Read the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements).
   In Go, you can do this is as well:

```
for i := 0; i < len(numbers); i++
```

But `range` clause is much more powerful once you understand it and yes it is not strange syntax. I'd suggest to read the spec and see a few examples.

4. Also, it's Go and not GoLang ([Read](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang)). Always prefer the former over the latter.
5. Try the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/). Some concepts are explained well.

Also, read Go's [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq) and [Pike's blog on declaration syntax](https://blog.golang.org/declaration-syntax). The FAQ should answer many such queries.